# my samsung galaxy s2 wont charge what do i do?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I'm having trouble with my Samsung galaxy s2 I need some help on how my phone can start charging again. Every time I got to charge my Samsung S2 it seems not to charge. I need some help on how to charge it.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if your charger is faulty or not by installing [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere&hl=en) app. If it not showing any in flow of mA after connecting, that means your charger is faulty. For the other way, you need to get your phone repaired.

Comment: i did download the app Ampere and it was not connecting so i guess i have to go get it repaired. but i dont think its my charger i think it is my phone because i have used several different chargers and they work perfectly for my family. do you know what else i can do?